# Measure associated to locally integrable function is regular

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Suppose $f \in L^{1}_\text{loc}(\mathbb{R}^{d})$ with $f \geq 0$ and create the measure $\mu$ such that $d\mu = f\, dx$ where $dx$ is the standard Lebesgue measure. Must $f$ be a regular measure?

Since $f$ is locally integrable, $\mu(K) < \infty$ for any compact $K$, but what about inner and outer regularity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: if $K$ is bounded, and a sequence of compacts $K_n$ fills $K$ ($K_n \to K$), then $\chi_{K_n}f\to \chi_K f$ a.e., and are dominated by $\chi_K |f|\in L^1$...
Similarly if a sequence of open sets $U_n\downarrow K$, there exists a compact containing $U_n$ for large $n$ ...